# The spectrum of a matrix operator is the set of its eigenvalues. But how to prove?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

I am studying spectral theory of functional analysis. I understand there are deep connections between the spectrum of operators and the eigenvalues of matrices. But I am unable to solve the following such a simple problem yet.

> Let $T$ be in a complex-valued matrix space, i.e., $T \in
>  \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$, equipped with the operator norm.
>
> 1. Show that the spectrum of $T$ is the set of its eigenvalues $\lambda_i$.
> 2. Use the Jordan decomposition to prove that the sequence $(\|T^n\|^\frac{1}{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}_{\ge 1}}$ converges towards the
>      spectral radius of $T$, i.e., $\|T^n\|^\frac{1}{n} \to
>     \max{|\lambda_i|}$ as $n \to \infty$.
> 3. Show that the sequence $(\|T^n\|^\frac{1}{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}_{\ge 1}}$ also converges, if $T$ is in a Banach algebra.

I think, if $T \in \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$, then $\|T\| := \sup \{\|Tx\|: x \in \mathbb{C}^n, \|x\| \le 1\}$. To show the spectrum of $T$, I know they are those $\lambda_i$ who make $(T - \lambda_i I)$ not invertible, then $(T - \lambda_i I) x_i = 0$ has non-trivial solution $x_i \ne 0$. I know the $x_i$ should be the eigenvectors due to $Tx_i = \lambda_i x_i$, and $\lambda_i$ should be the eigenvalues. **However, I am not sure if my statement above could be a proof of Q1.**

**For Q2 and Q3, I have totally no idea.** Could anyone help me to solve the problems, and to understand further the concepts behind spectrum and eigenvalues?

Comment: Yes, $Q1$ simply corresponds to the fact that a linear operator between vector spaces of the same finite dimension is injective if and only if it is invertible.

Comment: For $Q2$, if $T = S^{-1}JS$ is the Jordan decomposition of $T$, then $T^n = S^{-1}J^nS$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}||T^n||^{1/n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}||J^n||^{1/n}$; the explicit structure of $J^n$ is much easier to deal with.

Comment: For $Q3$, if $r_n = ||T^n||$, then $r_{m + n} \leqslant r_m r_n$. Starting with this, prove directly that $\lim_{n\to\infty} r_n^{1/n}$ exists and is equal to $\inf\{r_n^{1/n} : n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geqslant 1}\}$.

Comment: (See also a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius).)